# jQuery Image Slices

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've an image slider, in which I want to slice the image to create some kind of 3D-Effekt. I created the slider, but now I'm struggling with the responsive behavior of the slider.
In px values, everything is working finde, but I want the slider to be responsive.
Could somebody look at my code and give me a solution to solve the problem?
Here is my code:

The SCSS:

```
    /*Variables & Helper*/
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
%clearfix {
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('../img/bg.png');
}
img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.article{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    background: #fff;
    @extend %clearfix;
    padding: .8rem;
}
.img__container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.slice{
    float: left;
}
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $( window ).on('resize',function() {
        calcDimensions();
        bgPosition();
    });
    /*Variables*/
    var $imgContainer = $('.img__container'),
        $img          = $imgContainer.children('img'),
        slices        = 5,
        percentage    = 100 / slices + '%',
        imgWidth      = $imgContainer.width(),
        imgHeight     = $imgContainer.height();

    /**/
    sliceImg();

    /*Functions*/
    function calcDimensions(){
        imgWidth   = $imgContainer.width();
        imgHeight  = $imgContainer.height();
    };
    function bgPosition(){
        for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++){
                $('#slice' + i).css({
                    'background-position' : - ( (imgWidth / slices) * i ) + 'px 0%',
                });
            };
    }
    function sliceImg(){
        var imgLink    = $img.attr('src');
            /* Delete the image */
            $img.remove();

            /*Loop*/
            /*Create new divs*/
            for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++){
                var newDiv = $('<div></div>').addClass('slice').attr('id', 'slice' + i);
                $imgContainer.append(newDiv);
            };
            /**/
            bgPosition();
            $('.slice').css({
                'background-image' : 'url(' + imgLink + ')',
                'width'            : percentage,
                'height'           : imgHeight ,
                'background-size'  : 'cover',
            });
    };  



});
```

So, if i resize the window, it's kind of responsive. But not as great as a real responsive experience.
I also tried something like that, which should be  the right mathematic operation. But in jQuery i can't do mathematic operations with %, or am I wrong? Because I'm always getting errors....

```
$('.slice').css({
                'background-image' : 'url(' + imgLink + ')',
                'width'            : (imgWidth / slices / 100 * 1%) ,
                'height'           : imgHeight ,
                'background-size'  : 'cover',
            });
```

I'm looking forward to get a solution.
Thanks!

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You said you used 'px', so I think everything will go well if you use 'em' instead of 'px'.  And correct me If I am wrong, but I think you might want to use Dootstrap for responsive design.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't think em's will work in this example. Also bootstrap will not work, because I've to calculate the dimensions in JavaScript to get the image-slice effect.